# Smooth movement in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm starting to learn unity and I am facing a problem I can't get rid of, which is: however I tried to make the movement smooth it's not like usual video games, no matter how high the FPS is or how many different ways I try to implement the logic.

I tried to use fixed update and fixed delta time but nothing seems to make a difference.

```
void Update()
{

    movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    if ((movement > 0 && lookingLeft) || (movement < 0 && !lookingLeft))
    {
        lookingLeft = !lookingLeft;
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
    }
    if (noOfJumps > 0 || jumping)
        jumpInput = Input.GetAxis("Jump");
    if (jumpInput > 0 && !jumping)
    {
        pressTime = 0;
        jumping = true;
        noOfJumps--;

    }
    else if (jumpInput == 0)
        jumping = false;
    else
        pressTime += Time.deltaTime;

    if (pressTime > 0.15f)
        jumpInput = 0;

}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rd.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(rd.velocity, new Vector2(movement != 0 ? speed *
    movement * Time.fixedDeltaTime : rd.velocity.x * 0.95f, (jumpInput != 0) ? jumpInput * jumpSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime : -1), 0.9f);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning directly to velocity can overwrite certain calculations each frame. Best to use `AddForce` to avoid overriding changes due to gravity & friction.

Let the smoothing that `Input.GetAxis` puts into `movement` do the smoothing for you. Just multiply that value by speed to get the new horizontal speed.

Also, you're changing velocity, so you don't need to multiply your speed field by `Time.fixedDeltaTime`.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    float newVerticalVelocity = rd.velocity.y + jumpInput * jumpSpeed;
    Vector2 velocityChange =   newVerticalVelocity * Vector2.up 
                             + movement * speed * Vector2.right 
                             - rd.velocity;
    rd.AddForce(velocityChange, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

Comment: Is it okay to add force in every update ? This concept is pretty confusing to me.

Comment: Yes, because if you're already moving at the speed you should be going at, `velocityChange` is going to be `Vector2.zero`

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem is in the way you get the input from the user.

If you use Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") this will give you a value BETWEEN -1 and 1 and that value will be proportional to how hard or how long has the player been pressing the button.

Try using **.GetAxisRaw()** instead of **.GetAxis()**, this way you will just get the value -1 or 1 depending on the direction the player is moving and this will result in a more snappier movement

```
 movement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
```

Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IINXTKRey8) on the topic

Comment: The thing is I want the float value because I need it to be more realistic. That's why I need the getAxis value.