# Smooth ball movement (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a simple 3D game with ball. And the ball moves not smoothly.

```
while (i < Input.touchCount)
        {
            if(Input.GetTouch(i).position.y < ScreenHeight / 2)
            {
                if (Input.GetTouch(i).position.x > ScreenWidth / 2)
                {
                    //move right
                    rigidBody.velocity += new Vector3(0.75f, 0, 0);

                }
                if (Input.GetTouch(i).position.x < ScreenWidth / 2)
                {
                    //move left
                    rigidBody.velocity -= new Vector3(0.75f, 0, 0);

                }
            }
            ++i;
        }
```

As you can see I used rigid body's velocity and it starts slowly and then goes fast. But I want the ball to move immediately with constant velocity after touching the screen.
Also it is moving with jerks, not smoothly. 
Could you please help me improve it ?

Comment: If you want it to move at a constant velocity, you should be using regular assignment: `=` instead of `-=` and `+=`. So it would be `rigidBody.velocity = new Vector(x,y,z)`

Comment: And I have to mention that the ball just stays on the spot and moves only in x axis.

Comment: It's not moving on y axis because the Y value in your vector is 0

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the ball si using a rigidbody, so physics will come into play. All the += and -= on every frame (unless GetTouch is like GetKeyDown) is probably not ideal either as it will continue to accelerate the ball. I suggest doing as @Chronicle says and then maybe go into the rigidbody properties and set the ball as Kinematic, so that outside forces do't interact with it.

Comment: Hi, @Davrick consider using Lerping in order to make a movement to run smoothly, see [docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)

Comment: There was a ball controller in Standard Assets... It worked with rigidbody.AddTorque(), you can try it

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that physics calculations need to be in the `FixedUpdate()` event method:

**From [MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)**

> Frame-rate independent MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate message for physics calculations.
>
> MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate has the frequency of the physics system; it is called every fixed frame-rate frame. Compute Physics system calculations after FixedUpdate. 0.02 seconds (50 calls per second) is the default time between calls. Use Time.fixedDeltaTime to access this value.

**References:**

- [Why should you update physics in FixedUpdate?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1014110/why-should-you-update-physics-in-fixedupdate.html)
- [Smooth movement in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332252/smooth-movement-in-unity?rq=1)
- https://www.unity3dtips.com/unity-fix-movement-stutter/

Hopes it will helps.